# Mongostat says DB has a high lock percentage but thereare no insert/updates going on

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to interpret the results from mongostat.

We are running some stress test which only perform read operations on the DB. This is confirmed by the first columns of mongostat which reports around 6K queries per second, 0 insert, 0 updates, 0 deletes.

Still, the "locked db" field reports the DB being locked about 40% of the time, with about 130 queued reads, 0 queued writes.

Mongo version is 2.2 running on a Linux set of boxes (replica set with 2 nodes + 1 arbiter).

Can you help me understand what's going on? I though the lock was due to writes, but there are no writes in my test scenario.

Comment: Are you sure, there are no writes ? Please, post the output of mongostat and mongotop

Comment: Could you copy/paste few seconds of your mongostat output? If you could post output of mongostat --discover which includes all the members that'd be very helpful.

Comment: @Maziyar: unfortunately I am not in the position to execute the stress test again, since that environment has since gone live. Luckily as of now the traffic is way below the levels we've reached during our stress tests :)

Comment: Thanks Stefano, happy to see your problem has been sorted out.

Answer (score -1):

I think the MongoDb use Readers–writer lock ,which means the read will also get the lock at the same time, it allow a group of read request or one write request to get the lock. Hope can help you.

This is the wiki page of the Readers–writer lock .
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock